# "how you get paid" did not appear in AdMob account

Tags: android, admob, payment

I create a google AdMob account 6 months ago.

recently, I start to use it,

but I can't select a payment method from the payment setting because the "how you get paid" option didn't appear!

this is the screenshot

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFaCm.png

[image: this is the screenshot]

is this a problem? and how can I solve it?

Comment: seems like an issue with this service specifically, doesn't seem directly related to android/programming in a way that we can help, you should probably contact support, i would guess

Comment: Did you find the solution to this? I am also facing the same problem. I have just started the revenue. Are you sure, it won't appear only after the revenue reaches the threshold?

Comment: Hey! I got the solution! I am gonna answer. Please accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to google payment threshold [page](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/2772208). The option to get paid is only visible when the account has reached the threshold.
So, it is okay if you don't see it now. Just wait to cross the threshold.

Comment: i have just created a new account and applied for verification from adsense, its verified on adsense but to generate ads reveneu first it should also verify admob account right? i cant see any payment details in admob, what shall i do ? app shows "Getting ready" and it cant reach the threshold before it approve

Comment: @Viral have you figured this out? I have the same problem. It seem like a proper deadlock

Comment: @Bonco I was using Brave Browser, which was blocking some URLs as it was considering those as ADS, I just turned off Brave to protect ads and filter on admob and it worked. Which browser are you using?

Comment: @Viral I'm using Google Chrome, and have ad blocker paused. It seems that the problem resolved itself after a few days though. Now it says `Your account is approved` so I guess now it's ready to go

Comment: Great !! Congratulations! glad to know that